# How do I get Vue syntax Highlight for .js files in VSCode?

Tags: vue.js, vetur

I'm aware that I can have it with Vetur in the .vue files, but I use a lot of vue in the normal .js files. And I can't have syntax highligthing for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old but in case anyone is looking for an answer look for "Javascript Vue" extension it will highlit code in backticks `<div> this will have syntax highlighting </div>`